# Diesel engine smoking

Tags: ford, diesel, diesel-particulate-filter, transit

So I am currently working on a Ford Transit 2013 Diesel. The vehicle had a startup problem. I went ahead to change the turbo, fuel filter, and even had to extract the DPF from its chamber (because forced regeneration was not successful), re-programmed the pcm and changed the DPF sensor. The vehicle started now but it's smoking, black smoke when in motion. I have changed and calibrated the injectors but it still occurs. I am currently thinking of changing the DPF to a new one.

Any suggestions on what else to check please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!